# Whats the purpose of torch.positive?

Tags: python, pytorch

From the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.positive.html#torch.positive):

> `torch.positive(input)` → `Tensor`
>
> Returns `input`. Throws a runtime error if input is a bool tensor.

It just returns the input and throws error if its a `bool` tensor, but that's not an efficient nor readable way of checking if a tensor is `bool`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like pytorch added `pytorch.positive` [in parity with `numpy`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/55891) which has a [function of the same name](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.positive.html).

So back to your question, `positive` is a unary operator which basically multiplies everything by `+1`. This is not a particularly useful operation, but is symmetric to `negative` which multiplies everything by `-1`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> np.positive(a)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> np.negative(a)
array([ 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9])
```

So why make a `positive` function that effectively returns (a copy of) the array you passed? It can be used to write general code where e.g. `numpy.positive` and `numpy.negative` can be used dynamically based on some condition.